Rolling Rank Groupby
I am trying to get rolling rank based on group by. This is my demo data and "Rolling 2Y Rank' is expected column.
The way how it works is I intend to group by each "ID" and calculate rank based on its own historical "Value".
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003],
    'ID': ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
    'Value': [5,1,2,3,4,3,2,7,1,1,13,23],
    'Rolling 2Y Rank': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, 2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1]})




Year
ID
Value
Rolling 2Y Rank




2000
A
5
nan


2000
B
1
nan


2000
C
2
nan


2001
A
3
2


2001
B
4
1


2001
C
3
1


2002
A
2
2


2002
B
7
1


2002
C
1
2


2003
A
1
2


2003
B
13
1


2003
C
23
1



For example, for "ID"="A":

For first instance ("Year"=="2020"), there is no only one data, so it has nothing to compare against so it is NA.
For second instance, we compare 3 with 5 (rolling 2-year window), so we get rank 2 (because 5 is larger than 3).
For the third instance, we compare 2 against 3, so get the rank of 2 and so on so forth.

df[df['ID']=='A']

I have tried and it did not work out:
df.groupby('ID')['Value'].rolling(2).rank()


Paste your input and expected output in table format

@PrathikKini The desired output is Rolling 2Y Rank. I added the table.

You want the reversed (descending) rank, so pass that to the rank function. Then you can do a merge to assign back to the original dataframe:
df = df.merge(
    df.groupby('ID').rolling(2, on='Year')['Value'].rank(ascending=False),
    on=['ID','Year'],
)

Output:
    Year ID  Value_x  Value_y
0   2000  A        5      NaN
1   2000  B        1      NaN
2   2000  C        2      NaN
3   2001  A        3      2.0
4   2001  B        4      1.0
5   2001  C        3      1.0
6   2002  A        2      2.0
7   2002  B        7      1.0
8   2002  C        1      2.0
9   2003  A        1      2.0
10  2003  B       13      1.0
11  2003  C       23      1.0


Here is a way using .rolling().agg()
df.groupby('ID')['Value'].rolling(2).agg(lambda x: x.rank(method = 'dense',ascending=False).iloc[-1]).droplevel(0).sort_index()

Output:
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     2.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     2.0
7     1.0
8     2.0
9     2.0
10    1.0
11    1.0

